# Create Points at 10 Meter intervals along line with QChainge

Tags: qgis, qchainage

I have a route network and want to add every 10 meters a point with the 'QChainage' plugin.

I first used 'join multiple lines' to make the route a single section.
Then I transferred my CRS to my corresponding UTM-zone, to work with meters.

Changed 'Chainage every ' to 10 Meters and pressed Ok.

[image]

As result, however, I get only one Point.

[image]

The 'Devide Feature into x Parts' under 'Advanced ' seems to work, but it is not what I am looking for, since I want specific Distance.

[image]

Does anybody have an Idea what I can do, to make it work? I searched similar question regarding my task, but the answer always suggests to use the plugin, which I can't get to work.

Answer (score 2):

QGIS 3.0 has the tool *Points along geometry* which creates points at specified distance along a line, with distance along the line as an attribute. Here's the tool's description:

> Creates points at regular intervals along line or polygon geometries.
>   Created points will have new attributes added for the distance along
>   the geometry and the angle of the line at the point. An optional start
>   and end offset can be specified, which controls how far from the start
>   and end of the geometry the points should be created.

QGIS 2.18 has the tool, *Create points along lines.* This tool has no description, but the name and parameters are similar, so it seems likely that it does the same thing.

[image]